# Download a document from Ibm watson discovery response

Tags: javascript, node.js, watson-conversation, watson-discovery

I am trying to integrate watson conversation (assistant) with ibm watson discovery . Its a chatbot for hr , where you can type cv requirements like location , position etc and the api returns cvs containing those keywords.

The issue is the query returns a json response with text and various other fields like document id , file name etc however I cannot find anything that can act as a download link for the original file .

Actually I need the actual files pulled from the discovey api for the employers to download.I am using node js , Please help
Link to documentation :  https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/node.html?node

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand this, is that you have already access to the source of your documents when you add them to a collection.
Sometimes you can reconstruct the URL/location by just the filename in other cases you can supply this in the metadata when you add the document (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/curl.html?curl#add-document)

This means that you create a link to the source (and not to the Discovery Service) from where users can download the content.